# get fault information from a webinvoke method using WebClient

Tags: wcf, rest, exception

I am using new WebClient(url).UploadString(... to invoke a WCF WebInvoke web method.
The method is throwing a fault exception.

Is there any way to get more detailed error information other than
"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

I am throwing a fault (FaultException) with all the relevant information in it.

Regards
Craig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    string result = client.UploadString(
            "http://localhost:8080/method",
            "POST",
            xml.ToString()
    );
    result.Dump();
} catch (WebException ex) {
    XNamespace exn = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";        
    var error = from node in XElement.Load(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).Descendants(exn + "p")
                select node.Value;
    error.Dump();
}
```